# Greens function for forward propagating waves

Tags: greens-functions, propagator

I would like to find a form of a Green's function which accounts for the propagation of spherical waves expanding out from the spatial point $r$, but restricted to the forward propagating direction only. This would essentially require a half--sphere as the region of propagation (which would be true if mirrors where placed along one side of the sources.).

If we firstly remove the criteria of special boundary conditions by requiring the photons to propagate homogeneously propagating over the surface of a sphere, the Greens function may be found from the reduced wave equation (the Helmholtz equation). This would give

$\frac{e^{ikR}}{R}$, where R is the distant from the source to the detector plane. How could this be generalised for a propagator in $n$--dimensions?

Comment: "which would be true if mirrors where placed along one side of the sources" – This means you are looking for a Greens function for a special boundary condition (which you then want to apply to a special source distribution)? (Note, however, that a source at the boundary might lead to inconvenient subtleties). Also note that your setting requires a half-space (not a half sphere) as region of propagation.

Comment: @SebastianRiese, updated question